# como agregar una funcion a zshrc

Tags: regex, zsh

estoy intentando agregar una funcion a la zshrc, es un simple [script](https://pastebin.com/tYpwpauW).sh que contiene una funcion que utiliza regex para enumerar los puertos abiertos de una direccion, estoy intentando agregar dicha funcion para poder ejecutarla mediante el comando `extractPorts`, la idea es obviamente agregar la funcion para ejecutarla desde la shell sin tener que buscar y ejecutar el archivo todo el tiempo.

cuando ejecuto un

```
> source tYpwpauW.sh
```

y luego ejecuto

```
> which extractPorts
```

la consola me devueve la funcion.

```
> extractPorts () {

    ports="$(cat $1 | grep -oP '\d{1,5}/open' | awk '{print $1}' FS='/' | xargs | tr ' ' ',')"
    ip_address="$(cat $1 | grep -oP '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}' | sort -u | head -n 1)"
    echo -e "\n[*] Extracting information...\n" > extractPorts.tmp
    echo -e "\t[*] IP Address: $ip_address" >> extractPorts.tmp
    echo -e "\t[*] Open ports: $ports\n" >> extractPorts.tmp
    echo $ports | tr -d '\n' | xclip -sel clip
    echo -e "[*] Ports copied to clipboard\n" >> extractPorts.tmp
    cat extractPorts.tmp
    rm extractPorts.tmp
}
```

pero esto no me esta funcionando por que a la hora de leer un archivo la consola me devuelve `extractPorts: command not found: ^M` 
algo estoy haciendo mal, se agradece su ayuda, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta exportar la funcion en tu archivo `tYpwpauW.sh` una vez que ha sido declarada, lo harias asi:

```
export -f extractPorts
```

Por lo que veo tu funcion `extractPorts` recibe un argumento como parametro, asi que no olvides llamar a esta funcion pasandole su respectivo argumento.